# Mysql Convert Column to row

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

i have  problem mysql queris dynamic convert columns into rows,

I have a table like this :

| id | Nama Blok | Tahun_tanam | Luas | Jumlah_pokok |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Blok 1 | 2000 | 100 | 300 |
| 2 | Blok 2 | 1998 | 300 | 500 |

And then I want to create report like this :

| Blok | Blok 1 | Blok 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tahun Tanam | 2000 | 1998 |
| Luas | 100 | 300 |
| Jumlah Pokok | 300 | 500 |

help me solution query mysql, thanks.....

Comment: I think the term you are looking for is [Pivot Table and here is a good Q & A on that for you to start your research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786) But how you would create the `Blok` column from that table I have no idea, my magicians credentials have lapsed

Comment: Yes He must be looking for pivot with case expression and max function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I return pivot table output in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT
   'Blok' AS Attribute,
    MAX(CASE WHEN `Nama Blok` = 'Blok 1' THEN `Nama Blok` END) AS `Blok 1`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN `Nama Blok` = 'Blok 2' THEN `Nama Blok` END) AS `Blok 2`
   FROM your_table
   UNION
   SELECT
   'Tahun Tanam' AS Attribute,
   MAX(CASE WHEN `Nama Blok` = 'Blok 1' THEN `Tahun_tanam` END) AS `Blok 1`,
   MAX(CASE WHEN `Nama Blok` = 'Blok 2' THEN `Tahun_tanam` END) AS `Blok 2`
   FROM your_table
   UNION
   SELECT
  'Luas' AS Attribute,
  MAX(CASE WHEN `Nama Blok` = 'Blok 1' THEN `Luas` END) AS `Blok 1`,
  MAX(CASE WHEN `Nama Blok` = 'Blok 2' THEN `Luas` END) AS `Blok 2`
   FROM your_table
   UNION
   SELECT
  'Jumlah Pokok' AS Attribute,
   MAX(CASE WHEN `Nama Blok` = 'Blok 1' THEN `Jumlah_pokok` END) AS `Blok 1`,
  MAX(CASE WHEN `Nama Blok` = 'Blok 2' THEN `Jumlah_pokok` END) AS `Blok 2`
  FROM your_table;
```